# passing context into register form

Tags: python, django

I have a registration page, how can I pass the context to the header to display information in the header from the database

*view*

```
class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = '/login/'
    template_name = 'essense/registration.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()

        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass data using `get_context_data`

```
class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = "/login/"
    template_name = "essense/registration.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegisterFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # here you can pass any type of data
        context["variable_name"] = "value"
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()

        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: forgot about this function)